# Gwt create panel with standard html tags

Tags: html, gwt, tags, panel

I want to create an web application in gwt where I need to have standard custom tags like header, footer, nav etc.
But my problem is whenever I use a panel in gwt java code the underneath compiler produces either a div element or table element, but never produces something like header or footer or nav. Please can anyone suggest me best practice to create or have panel with standard tags like header and footer.
One approach could be ui binder but I am not using it and want to stick to basic gwt approach.

I also tried this approach :

HtmlPanel panel = new HtmlPanel("");

It does create a footer tag but then this footer is wrapped under table tag of HtmlPanel and I have no reference to this footer from java code.
Please can someone help me on this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the above answers the best and standard practice I used was:

FlowPanel footerpanel = new FlowPanel("footer");

By using flow panel I was able to create my custom standard tag in underneath html and also I got a handler to it in my Java code where I could add widgets as needed in my java code.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options: work with Elements or use a HTMLPanel.
Here is an example for each solution:

```
    //Element
    Element footerElement = Document.get().createElement("footer");
    Document.get().getBody().appendChild(footerElement);

    //HTMPPanel
    HTMLPanel footer= new HTMLPanel("footer", "Hello footer");
    RootPanel.get().add(footer);
```

anyway I cant tell you what is best practice here...